# Running Cakephp with 775 file permission

Tags: cakephp

We have developed one project on cakephp for a govt. entity. After  development the server provider for this govt. entity told us that they won't be providing 777 file permission on the server as this is against their guidelines. Now we need a solution to run this with 775 file permission. Any way out for this ?

This is what they told us

"Write and Read Permission can be given to only one folder i.e WriteReadData. No customized folder is allowed. Yes you can create as many folder under WriteReadData folder. And in Web Server environment only 775 permission."

Please suggest how to run this application.

Comment: So why is that a problem? Just set permission for folder "tmp" and it's subfolders to 775. Then all you have to do is make sure that the user used to create the folders is in same group and group for webserver user, or change the owner of the folders to webserver user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a real problem in there ?
Just check your tmp folder, here is a link for more infos -> [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

### 777 permissions are not required

**Or** a good idea.

The problem is really ownership, not permissions. An app should always run [on the principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), i.e. the minimum permissions to permit it to function. Applied to the tmp folder (which is the only folder that needs to be writable) that could simply mean:

```
[ app ]
-> chown -R www-data:www-data tmp
[ app ]
-> chmod -R 700 tmp
[ app ]
-> ls -la
total 44
dr-xr-xr-x 11 root     root     4096 May 20 14:46 .
dr-xr-xr-x  6 root     root     4096 Jun 11 15:28 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Jun 13 07:34 Config
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May 22 14:10 Console
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May 22 14:10 Controller
dr-xr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 May  6 09:42 Locale
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May 15 09:21 Model
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Feb 25 10:40 Plugin
drwx------  5 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 23 14:33 tmp
dr-xr-xr-x 10 root     root     4096 Feb 25 10:40 View
dr-xr-xr-x  7 root     root     4096 Jun 11 15:28 webroot
```

Where `www-data` is the webserver user.

Comment: While I agree about ``tmp``, I don't see why app dirs should belong to root and be ``r-x`` by everyone. IMO they should belong to a restricted user with ``rwx`` rights, having group ``www-data`` with ``r-x`` and ``---`` for everyone else. Obviously files shouldn't be ``x`` unless for ``cake`` (if needed).

Comment: @user221931 They can belong to anyone - so long as apache has read and execute permissions. It's implied because of the way the question is written that the webserver user is neither the owner or group owner of the files (nothing "wrong" with that so didn't change it). [No executable perms on a folder means you can't access the contents](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/14886) and the app just won't work - note that everything shown is a directory.

Comment: If you read my comment again I do have ``x`` for dirs and never meant to remove it (just added it shouldn't be on files as a lot of people would chmod 775 -R which will include files). What bothers me with your answer is that you give read/directory parsing access to anyone and you require someone to su or sudo to change some file.

Comment: @user221931 `I don't see why app dirs should [...] be r-x by everyone.` <- then somehow I am misreading that. You're welcome to write a different answer to resolve the bother, despite it not being the question.

Comment: @user221931 and infact `IMO they should belong to a restricted user with rwx rights` <- so you **want** all application files to be writable... well that's an exploit waiting to happen. **Don't** make files writable that don't need to be.

Comment: Yes I agree, that one slipped, I would have liked to change my original comment for future readers but can't now, hope they get up to here.